# Pandas: using iterrows to return calculated values

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying and failing to use `iterrows` with if/else statements to return calculated values from DataFrame columns. Am starting to think it's the wrong method.

In this example I have two variables `x` and `y`, and a DataFrame:

```
    category    number
0   one         13
1   two         14
2   one         7
3   three       8
4   one         3
5   two         8
6   four        9
```

If the category is one or two, divide the corresponding number by 2 and assign half the value to variable `x` and half to variable `y`. But if the category is three or four, assign the whole corresponding number to just variable `y`. `x` and `y` would then be  the summed result, as in:

`x = 22.5`
(Because: 13/2+14/2+7/2+3/2+8/2 = 22.5)

`y = 39.5`
(Because: 13/2+14/2+7/2+8+3/2+8/2+9 = 39.5)

I haven't found any example of `iterrows` being used like this. Are these types of calculations even possible using `iterrows` or is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to slice by each case you're looking at, and then aggregate as appropriate.

```
case1 = ['one', 'two']
case2 = ['three', 'four']
x = df.loc[df.category.isin(case1), 'number'].sum()/2
y = x + df.loc[df.category.isin(case2), 'number'].sum()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Had never considered combining `isin` with `loc` - such a powerful combination. Thanks.